# I am using odoo 14, when i try to inherit from from an existing module

Tags: python, inheritance, module, odoo, odoo-14

i get this error <Some modules are not loaded, some dependencies or manifest may be missing: ['netflix_module']>
I am trying to inherit from sales module but I don't understand the problem. I am sure spelling is correct.
[terminal error pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqASQ.png)

[terminal error pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpN1o.png)

[odoo error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93yq3.png)

here is my code it works fine without sales.py
[manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmpPJ.png)

[XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDY21.png)

[movie.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Y3t.png)

[res_partner.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzhz7.png)

[sales.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNuil.png)

Answer (score 0):

ok I have just solved the problem.
I must install sales first from odoo site, then apply the code.
I will leave the question for others, it may helps.

Comment: must include dependencies on __manifest__.py file instead of install the dependencies manually